# Error in regression analysis with 3 classes

Tags: python

I am trying to apply one vs all logistic regression:

I am using one vs all method (class1 vs class2+ class3, c2 vs c1+c3, c3 vs c1+c2) to calculate the three cases weights w1,w2,w3:

```
   for n1 in range(0,50000):

        s1 = np.dot(dt, w1)
        p1 = (1 / (1 + np.exp(-s1)))
        gr1 = (np.dot(dt.T, p1-c1))
        gr1 /= N
        w1 -= 0.01 * gr1

        if n1 % 10000 == 0 and n1!=0:
          loss1 = np.sum( np.log(1 + np.exp(s1))-p1*s1 )
          print('loss1',loss1)
```

dt is my features,

w1,w2,w3 are initialized as w1=np.zeros((5,1)),

```
c1=np.vstack((np.ones(40),np.zeros(40),np.zeros(40)))
c2=np.vstack((np.zeros(40),np.ones(40),np.zeros(40)))
c3=np.vstack((np.zeros(40),np.zeros(40),np.ones(40)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so. the iris data set is not perfect linearly separable in all the sets.
so wen we use a linear classifier like logistic regression the loss in the part that is not linearly separable tends to be unpredictable.
you can put a a very small learning hate and a patiently method to avoid overffitting.
normalization of you data between 0 and 1 will help too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response by patiently method do you refer to multiple iterations?

Comment: patiently method : you can define if the loss continue to decrease for a determined number of steps.

Comment: for example: if the loss don´t  decrease for 3 steps you can stop the training. this is method to avoid overffitting.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it